# iPhone Soap Web Service

Tags: iphone, soap, service, web

This is my first time that I will work with the web service, so I will be grateful to you if you can help me .

I have created this web service :

http://192.168.2.166:8080/WebService1/Service1.asmx
it includes three methods, the first one will return array of strings, the second and third will return one string for each method .

My question is : How can I connect with this web service and print the results on console ?

Note : if anybody have a good tutorial and advanced that related to web service, I will be grateful if he can shared this tutorial with me (specially how connect web service with database and return the results to the clients)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

follow this tutorials [Soap in iphone](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

I think your requirement are similiar with the following

[SOAPWebService](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather)

Comment: Thanks Ali3an, I have finished reading this tutorial but it's not clear enough to me, I don't know where should I change and where not !! , do you know another one ? Thanks a lot .